# Eigen: Return a reference to a block of a matrix with compile-time dimension checks

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

What I am asking is a generalization of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548253/eigen-library-return-a-matrix-block-in-a-function-as-lvalue). Specifically, I would like to make a C++ Eigen wrapper around a legacy C and Fortran library,  which uses a 2D data-structure:

```
[   x[0,0] ...   x[0,w-1] ]
[   u[0,0] ...   u[0,w-1] ]
[          ...            ]
[ x[c-1,0] ... x[c-1,w-1] ]
[ u[c-1,0] ... u[c-1,w-1] ]
```

where each of the entries `x[i,j]` and `u[i,j]` are themselves column vectors of size (`nx1`) and (`mx1`) respectively.
This leads to some complicated (and error prone) pointer arithmetic as well as some very unreadable code.

Therefore, I want to write an Eigen class whose sole purpose is to make extracting entries of this matrix as easy as possible. In C++14, that looks like this `data_getter.h`:

```
#ifndef DATA_GETTER_HEADER
#define DATA_GETTER_HEADER

#include "Eigen/Dense"

template<typename T, int n, int m, int c, int w>
class DataGetter {
public:

    /** Return a reference to the data as a matrix */
    static auto asMatrix(T *raw_ptr) {
        auto out = Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<T, (n + m) * c, w>>(raw_ptr);
        static_assert(decltype(out)::RowsAtCompileTime == (n + m) * c);
        static_assert(decltype(out)::ColsAtCompileTime == w);
        return out;
    }

    /** Return a reference to the submatrix
     * [ x[i,0], ..., x[i,w-1]]
     * [ u[i,0], ..., u[i,w-1]] */
    static auto W(T *raw_ptr, int i) {
        auto out = asMatrix(raw_ptr).template middleRows<n + m>((n + m) * i);
        static_assert(decltype(out)::RowsAtCompileTime == (n + m));
        static_assert(decltype(out)::ColsAtCompileTime == w);
        return out;
    }

    /** Return a reference to the submatrix [ x[i,0], ..., x[i,w-1]] */
    static auto X(T *raw_ptr, int i) {
        auto out = W(raw_ptr, i).template topRows<n>();
        static_assert(decltype(out)::RowsAtCompileTime == n);
        static_assert(decltype(out)::ColsAtCompileTime == w);
        return out;
    }

    /** Return a reference to x[i,j] */
    static auto X(T *raw_ptr, int i, int j) {
        auto out = X(raw_ptr, i).col(j);
        static_assert(decltype(out)::RowsAtCompileTime == n);
        static_assert(decltype(out)::ColsAtCompileTime == 1);
        return out;
    }

    /** Return a reference to the submatrix [ u[i,0], ..., u[i,w-1]] */
    static auto U(T *raw_ptr, int i) {
        auto out = W(raw_ptr, i).template bottomRows<m>();
        static_assert(decltype(out)::RowsAtCompileTime == m);
        static_assert(decltype(out)::ColsAtCompileTime == w);
        return out;
    }

    /** Return a reference to u[i,j] */
    static auto U(T *raw_ptr, int i, int j) {
        auto out = U(raw_ptr, i).col(j);
        static_assert(decltype(out)::RowsAtCompileTime == m);
        static_assert(decltype(out)::ColsAtCompileTime == 1);
        return out;
    }

    /** Return a reference to the submatrix
     * [ x[0,i], ..., x[c-1,i]]
     * [ u[0,i], ..., u[c-1,i]] */
    static auto C(T *raw_ptr, int i) {
        auto out = Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<T, n + m, c>>(
                asMatrix(raw_ptr).col(i).template topRows<(n + m) * c>().data());
        static_assert(decltype(out)::RowsAtCompileTime == (n + m));
        static_assert(decltype(out)::ColsAtCompileTime == c);
        return out;
    }

    /** Return a reference to the submatrix [ x[0,i], ..., x[c-1,i]] */
    static auto Xc(T *raw_ptr, int i) {
        auto out = C(raw_ptr, i).template topRows<n>();
        static_assert(decltype(out)::RowsAtCompileTime == n);
        static_assert(decltype(out)::ColsAtCompileTime == c);
        return out;
    }

    /** Return a reference to the submatrix [ u[0,i], ..., u[c-1,i]] */
    static auto Uc(T *raw_ptr, int i) {
        auto out = C(raw_ptr, i).template bottomRows<m>();
        static_assert(decltype(out)::RowsAtCompileTime == m);
        static_assert(decltype(out)::ColsAtCompileTime == c);
        return out;
    }
};

#endif /* DATA_GETTER_HEADER */
```

and here is a test program demonstrating how that works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Eigen/Dense"
#include "data_getter.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

template<typename T>
void printSize(MatrixBase<T> &mat) {
    cout << T::RowsAtCompileTime << " x " << T::ColsAtCompileTime;
}

int main() {

    using T = double;
    const int n = 2;
    const int m = 3;
    const int c = 2;
    const int w = 5;
    const int size = w * (c * (n + m));
    std::vector<T> vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        vec.push_back(i);

    /* Define the interface that we will use a lot */
    using Data = DataGetter<T, n, m, c, w>;

    /* Now let's map that pointer to some submatrices */
    Ref<Matrix<T, (n + m) * c, w>> allData = Data::asMatrix(vec.data());
    Ref<Matrix<T, n, w>> x1 = Data::X(vec.data(), 1);
    Ref<Matrix<T, n, c>> xc2 = Data::Xc(vec.data(), 2);
    Ref<Matrix<T, n + m, c>> xuc2 = Data::C(vec.data(), 2);
    Ref<Matrix<T, n, 1>> x12 = Data::X(vec.data(), 1, 2);

    cout << "Data::asMatrix( T* ): ";
    printSize(allData);
    cout << endl << endl << allData << endl << endl;
    cout << "Data::X( T*, 1 )    : ";
    printSize(x1);
    cout << endl << endl << x1 << endl << endl;
    cout << "Data::Xc( T*, 2 )   : ";
    printSize(xc2);
    cout << endl << endl << xc2 << endl << endl;
    cout << "Data::C( T*, 2 )    : ";
    printSize(xuc2);
    cout << endl << endl << xuc2 << endl << endl;
    cout << "Data::X( T*, 1, 2 ) : ";
    printSize(x12);
    cout << endl << endl << x12 << endl << endl;

    /* Now changes to x12 should be reflected in the other variables */
    x12.setZero();

    cout << "-----" << endl << endl << "x12.setZero() " << endl << endl << "-----" << endl;

    cout << "allData" << endl << endl << allData << endl << endl;
    cout << "x1" << endl << endl << x1 << endl << endl;
    cout << "xc2" << endl << endl << xc2 << endl << endl;
    cout << "xuc2" << endl << endl << xuc2 << endl << endl;
    cout << "x12" << endl << endl << x12 << endl << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Specifically, it produces the following output (as expected):

```
Data::asMatrix( T* ): 10 x 5

 0 10 20 30 40
 1 11 21 31 41
 2 12 22 32 42
 3 13 23 33 43
 4 14 24 34 44
 5 15 25 35 45
 6 16 26 36 46
 7 17 27 37 47
 8 18 28 38 48
 9 19 29 39 49

Data::X( T*, 1 )    : 2 x 5

 5 15 25 35 45
 6 16 26 36 46

Data::Xc( T*, 2 )   : 2 x 2

20 25
21 26

Data::C( T*, 2 )    : 5 x 2

20 25
21 26
22 27
23 28
24 29

Data::X( T*, 1, 2 ) : 2 x 1

25
26

-----

x12.setZero() 

-----
allData

 0 10 20 30 40
 1 11 21 31 41
 2 12 22 32 42
 3 13 23 33 43
 4 14 24 34 44
 5 15  0 35 45
 6 16  0 36 46
 7 17 27 37 47
 8 18 28 38 48
 9 19 29 39 49

x1

 5 15  0 35 45
 6 16  0 36 46

xc2

20  0
21  0

xuc2

20  0
21  0
22 27
23 28
24 29

x12

0
0
```

The issue is that the compile-time checks on the dimensions don't seem to be working. In the `data_getter.h`, you may notice that I put a bunch of `static_assert`s on the dimensions. That may seem like a bit of overkill, but I wanted to ensure that the expressions really are performing compile-time operations so that we can get checks on the dimensions. If they were dynamic expressions, then the sizes would all be -1.

However, despite the fact that all of the `static_assert`s pass, there doesn't seem to be any compile-time checking on the references. For instance, if we change the following line in the test program

```
Ref<Matrix<T, (n + m) * c, w>> allData = Data::asMatrix(vec.data());
```

into

```
Ref<Matrix<T, (n + m) * c + 1, w>> allData = Data::asMatrix(vec.data());
```

The code compiles, but yields a runtime crash. This seems to suggest that the `Ref` is discarding dimensions. So how should I be defining these variables?

One idea that may come to mind is to define these return values as `auto` as well. However, this is [explictly discouraged by the Eigen docs](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html) because if we end up using the output in a loop, it may lead to the expression being evaluated over and over again. That is the reason why I am using `Ref`s. Also, it just seems like a good idea to explicitly state the size since we know it at compile-time...

So is this a bug in Ref? and what type should I be using for the variables that are being spit out by all of my accessor methods?

Comment: Returnig `Ref<..>` should be the best option here. I'd need to check why that does not make compile-time checks of the sizes.

Comment: I was very surprised by this behavior

Comment: I put in a MWE to demonstrate this. Perhaps it runs differently on your system...

Comment: I did not check it yet (and I don't doubt that there may be an issue inside Eigen). Just to be sure: Are you on the most recent version of Eigen?

Comment: I pulled off the trunk a few weeks ago. But i will do it again tomorrow just to make sure.

Comment: I don't think anything relevant changed in the past weeks. Could you file a bug at http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/ ?

Comment: In the meantime, I never noticed that the syntax `.block(a,b,c,d)` returns a dynamically sized block, while `.block<c,d>(a,b)` is fixed size. I have to check what happens of I use that version

Comment: Yep. Will do if I can't figure it out by tomorrow

Comment: I would simply use `auto` as the return type (c++14) while writing the method's body to return fixed-size expressions.

Comment: I tried that with c++11 (and decltype) and I was getting a strange compiler error. I forget what now.

Comment: I updated to the bleeding edge, and I am still getting the errors with Ref

Comment: However, I am not totally convinced that the problem is with `Ref` here. I think it might be due to the fact that `a.topRows(n);` returns a matrix with a dynamic number of rows.

Comment: But I am not sure how to test that because the compile-time version `a.topRows<n>();` does not compile (see updated question).

Comment: Do you guys know why `topRows<n>()` might compile outside of a function, but not inside?

Comment: @ggael : I did a bunch of work on this since a week ago, and it does seem to be a bug in Ref. I would appreciate if you could reexamine the evidence in the reformulated question

Comment: @chtz Updated with more info...

Comment: I confirm that `Ref` is missing compile-time checks in its constructors. Sizes are checked only at runtime within the `MapBase` base class.

Comment: @ggael Is that a bug, or intended behavior?

Comment: This is a shortcoming.

Comment: @ggael so do you think that this functionality will get added in the future? Or would that require a major redesign?

Comment: Also... is there an alternative way to achieve the above behavior without `Ref`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you miss it in the comments... @ggael says that Eigen `Ref`s do not check dimensions at compile-time.

Comment: This is fixed: https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/commits/e1203d5ceb8e669f76fd643f4056b7e28d987077

Comment: @ggael Please post this as an answer so that you can get the bounty.