# Eigen: Efficient way of referencing ArrayWrapper

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen, eigen3

I am interfacing some code with raw pointers. So I have extensive use of the map class:

```
void foo(T* raw_pointer){
    const int rows = ...;
    const int cols = ...;
    Map<Matrix<T, rows, cols>> mat(raw_pointer);

    // DO some stuff with "mat"
}
```

Now I want to apply some cwise operations in `foo`, which I accomplish using `.array()`. The code works, however, it looks very messy due to all of the `.array()` calls strewn in the function. For instance, for the sake of argument, let's suppose that the function looked like this:

```
void foo(T* raw_pointer){
    const int rows = ...;
    const int cols = ...;
    Map<Matrix<T, rows, cols>> mat(raw_pointer);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; ++i)
        ... something = i * mat.row(1).array() * sin(mat.row(4).array()) + mat.col(1).array();
}
```

Part of the problem with this is that it is very unclear what the code is actually doing. It would be much nicer if gave the variables names:

```
void foo(T* raw_pointer){
    const int rows = ...;
    const int cols = ...;
    Map<Matrix<T, rows, cols>> mat(raw_pointer);

    Matrix<T, 1, cols> thrust = mat.row(1);
    Matrix<T, 1, cols> psi = mat.row(4);
    Matrix<T, 1, cols> bias = mat.row(2);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; ++i)
        ... something = i * thrust.array() * sin(psi.array()) + bias.array();
}
```

But it would be even nicer if I could get directly get a reference to the `ArrayWrapper`s so that we aren't making any copies. However, the only way I can figure out how to get that to work is by using `auto`:

```
void foo(T* raw_pointer){
    const int rows = ...;
    const int cols = ...;
    Map<Matrix<T, rows, cols>> mat(raw_pointer);

    auto thrust = mat.row(1).array();
    auto psi = mat.row(4).array();
    auto bias = mat.row(2).array();

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; ++i)
        ... something = i * thrust * sin(psi) + bias;
}
```

This code works, and upon testing appears to reference the entries in the pointer (as opposed to making copies like in the previous snippet). However, 
I am concerned about its efficiency since the Eigen documentation [explicitly suggests NOT doing this](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html). So could somebody please what the preferred way to define the types for the variables is in such a circumstance?

It seems to me like I should be using a `Ref` here, but I can't figure out how to get that to work. Specifically, I have tried replacing `auto` with

```
Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Array<T, 1, cols>>
```

and

```
Eigen::Ref<Eigen::ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<T, 1, cols>>>
```

but the compiler doesn't like either of those.

Comment: Two things: The `Ref` doesn't make a copy; You can use a `Map<Eigen::Array...` instead of a `Map<Eigen::Matrix...` to use elementwise operations by default.

Comment: Hmmm. The only problem is that we have a general interface class for getting an `Map<Eigen::Matrix` objects from the raw pointer. I guess I could just do `Map<Eigen::Array.. >>(mapMatrix.data())` on that object

Comment: Let me see if that will work for our case.

Comment: Hmm. It seems that that will indeed work. The only issue I am going to have is the loss of compile-time size checking. I think I can live with that though. You should post an answer...

Comment: Why do you lose anything compared to the `Map<Eigen::Matrix...`?

Comment: I have an interface file (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49008788/eigen-return-a-reference-to-a-block-of-a-matrix-with-compile-time-dimension-che) for accessing the raw data

Comment: That interface removes a lot of the boilerplate that I would otherwise need to have. It also ensures that the raw data is accessed consistently, so it should help reduces bugs. It also does size checking

Comment: Now if set `Map<Eigen::Matrix... >> mapMatrix = ` output of one of those functions, then I think I could `Map<Eigen::Array... >> mapArray(mapMatrix.data());`

Comment: Got it. And I see that [ggael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49008788/eigen-return-a-reference-to-a-block-of-a-matrix-with-compile-time-dimension-che#comment85385509_49147375) has since fixed the compile time checks.

Comment: However, in the definition of `mapArray`, I would have to redefine the dimensions. So I could potentially introduce a bug there that cannot be checked at compile-time

Comment: Ahh. Actually, this approach didn't work because of the strides in the underlying pointer when using my interface file. But it would work for the original question...

Comment: I'm not following. The third template parameter for `Eigen::Map` is the stride type. The third or fourth parameter of the `Map` c'tor is a runtime modifiable stride.

Comment: I would have to mess around with that. I guess that would be a viable alternative. But I do not have time to look into that now.

Comment: To get a `Ref` with inner stride, write `Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Array<T, 1, cols>, 0, Eigen::InnerStride<> >` (this is necessary, if you want to refer to a row of a column-major matrix/array).

Comment: This is a perfectly fine and safe usage of `auto`.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid having to write `array()` every time you use the `Map<Eigen::Matrix...` you can use a `Map<Eigen::Array...` instead/in addition. This will use the default element-wise operators instead of the matrix operators. To use a matrix operator instead, you can use `map.matrix()` (similar to what you have in your post `mat.array()`).

Comment: Similarly, you can/need to write `Array<T, 1, cols> thrust = mat.row(1);` etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
auto thrust = [](auto&&mat){return mat.row(1).array();};
auto psi = [](auto&&mat){return mat.row(4).array();};
auto bias = [](auto&&mat){return mat.row(2).array();};

for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; ++i)
    ... something = i * thrust(mat) * sin(psi(mat)) + bias(mat)
```

has names.  And the array wrappers don't persist.